# PHP - parsing big data and keeping them up to date

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, bigdata

I use PHP for solving this task. But that's not the point.

Every morning I get four files each of them contains nearly 6000-8000 records having the following form:

- Product name
- Package
- Producer
- Price with tax
- Expire date
- Rest
- Series

Parsing these records I get the table of products. Later clients make orders so I need to keep id of item in the order table. (clients would like to see history of purchases)

All is fine. The arising problem is that one day any of suppliers can send completely different price list. I.e. some products will be removed and others will be added. So it would be completely wrong to rely upon they order in the price list.

What I've come to is to parse catalog blindly adding all items one time. Every next time when I  get catalog I need to add only new items and remove the old one from DB. (though not actually removing but just marking as deleted so that no new purchases would be possible )

For deciding whether item is new or not I will retrieve record by record from Excel file and check  "Product name", "package", "producer", "series" fields in conjunction against the table with products.

If no such item is found I assume that this is a new item and I'll add it to DB.

What to do with deleted items? I'm not warned about deletion of them. So I can't find out what items are missing in the new Excel file. The solution is to scan DB item by item and see whether all items in DB are present in Excel file. If some item is missing  then I will mark  it as deleted.

Once deleted items can be back for selling. So I will need to select all deleted items and check one by one against Excel file. If item appears in Excel file - I add it back.

It's worth to note that some suppliers give their catalogs as Excel files and others as DBF files as for now.  Who knows what formats will come in the future. Also the number of suppliers is supposed to grow up (next month we get 2 more into play).

My question. Is there any better way to do it more efficient? I'm afraid that my method is too straightforward.

Having 8000 records and doing 3 checks I will get O^2 complexity for every price list making whole search through MySQL Db. Perhaps it will work for 8000 records but I'm sure it's going to fail when one day I get price list with let's say 10^5 record.

Is there a better way to organise it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for the record: 8,000 records per day may present a few programming challenges, but it is hardly "big data." 8,000 per hour might qualify, but when people talk about big data, they typically mean more like billions of records, coming in at rates more like a few hundred or a few thousand per minute.

Comment: Insert the records to a second table with the same structure. Then you can run just two queries. One to update the price(s) (and other fields that need updating) where the records in the primary table exist and then a second to insert new records where they don't exist. And I guess maybe a third if you need to remove records that aren't in the list if the list is all inclusive.

Comment: How about update timestamp from all records from file and on a second run on the database set the ones with an older timestamp to status "delete". That seems faster and less complex.

Comment: Ed Cottrell - totally agree, couldn't figure out a better name. Perhaps I should rename the topic. What do you think?  Jonathan Kuhn - got it. Sound like a good improvement.  Danilel - I didn't get the idea. Records in Excel file don't have any timestamps. Do you mean that when I find any record in DB I should update its timestamp in the table so that there would be no need to  check second time whether record is present or not? Ah, I got it if you meant this.